# Как удалить последний выведенный символ?

Tags: pascal

Как удалить последний выведенный символ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код забоя - это #8. Поэтому отправка забоя, а значит и удаление последнего выведенного символа:

```
Write(#8);
```

или

```
Write(#8+' '+#8);
```